# Apache Flink - how to skip all but most recent window on startup

Tags: apache-flink

In Flink, I have a Job with a Keyed Stream of events (e.g.: 10 events for each Key every day on average).
They are handled as Sliding Windows based on Event-Time (e.g.: 90-days window size and 1-day window slide).
Events are consumed from Kafka, which persists all event history (e.g.: last 3 years).

Sometimes I'd like to restart Flink: for maintenance, bug handling, etc. 
Or start a fresh Flink instance with Kafka already containing event history.

In such case I would like to skip triggering for all but the most recent window for each Key.
(It's specific to my use-case: each window, when processed, effectively overrides processing results from previous windows. So at startup, I would like to process only single most recent window for each Key.)

Is it possible in Flink? If so, then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer<T> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(...);
myConsumer.setStartFromTimestamp(...); // start from specified epoch timestamp (milliseconds)
```

which is described along with other related functions in the section of the docs on [Kafka Consumers Start Position Configuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration).

Or you could use a [savepoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/state/savepoints.html) to do a clean upgrade/redeploy without losing your kafka offsets and associated window contents.